# Codeigniter 3.1.4 con Eloquent 5.4 Servicio

Tags: php, webservice, codeigniter-3, orm, eloquent

Controlador Servicios para obtener PREMIOS incluyendo count y paginado

Este es mi controlador de servicios, con CODEIGNITER 3.4 y ELOQUENT 5.4

```
public function __construct()
{

    parent::__construct();

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    if (!$this->lib_validaciones->validarSesion(FALSE))
    {
        exit(json_encode(array("satisfactorio" => FALSE, "mensaje" => "NO TIENE SESSION ACTIVA")));
    }
    $this->usuarioId = $this->session->userdata("usuarioId");
}

public function index()
{
    exit();
}

public function getPremios()
{
    $currentPage = $this->input->get("pag");

    \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::currentPageResolver(function () use ($currentPage)
    {
        return $currentPage;
    });

    $this->load->model('Premio');

    $premios = Premio::where('activo', "TRUE")
            ->with(['Categoria' => function($q)
                {
                    $q->select('id', 'nombre');
                }])
            ->with(['Imagenes' => function ($query)
                {
                    $query->where("activo", "TRUE");
                    $query->select(["imagenes.id", "imagenes.descripcion",
                        new Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression(
                                "CONCAT('" . site_url(PATH_IMAGENES_UPLOAD) . "',imagenes.id,'.',imagenes.extension) as path")
                    ]);
                }])
            ->with(['inventario'])
            ->withCount(['Favoritos', 'Favoritos AS favorito_usuario' => function ($query)
                {
                    $query->where("usuario_id", $this->usuarioId);
                }])
            ->orderBy("nombre")
            ->paginate(3);

    $premios->setPath(site_url(uri_string()));
    $premios->setPageName("pag");

    exit(json_encode(array("satisfactorio" => TRUE, "premios" => $premios->toArray())));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta: 
{
  "satisfactorio": true,
  "premios": {
    "total": 12,
    "per_page": 3,
    "current_page": 2,
    "last_page": 4,
    "next_page_url": "http://10.10.10.10/proyect/servicios/getPremios?pag=3",
    "prev_page_url": "http://10.10.10.10/proyect/servicios/getPremios?pag=1",
    "from": 4,
    "to": 6,
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "activo": "TRUE",
        "etiqueta": "NO",
        "nombre": "ENTRADAS AL CINE",
        "descripcion": "",
        "puntos_requeridos": 300,
        "categoria_id": 4,
        "creado_a": "2017-05-11 09:20:27",
        "actualizado_a": null,
        "favoritos_count": 0,
        "favorito_usuario_count": 0,
        "categoria": {
          "id": 4,
          "nombre": "OTROS"
        },
        "imagenes": [],
        "inventario": null
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "activo": "TRUE",
        "etiqueta": "NO",
        "nombre": "EXTRACTOR DE JUGO FPSTJE317S",
        "descripcion": "NINGUNA",
        "puntos_requeridos": 1200,
        "categoria_id": 1,
        "creado_a": "2017-05-05 16:02:54",
        "actualizado_a": null,
        "favoritos_count": 0,
        "favorito_usuario_count": 0,
        "categoria": {
          "id": 1,
          "nombre": "PRODUCTOS OSTER"
        },
        "imagenes": [],
        "inventario": null
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "activo": "TRUE",
        "etiqueta": "NO",
        "nombre": "LICUADORA 6455",
        "descripcion": "NINGUNA",
        "puntos_requeridos": 1000,
        "categoria_id": 1,
        "creado_a": "2017-05-05 16:02:54",
        "actualizado_a": null,
        "favoritos_count": 2,
        "favorito_usuario_count": 1,
        "categoria": {
          "id": 1,
          "nombre": "PRODUCTOS OSTER"
        },
        "imagenes": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "descripcion": "LICUADORA OSTER",
            "path": "http://10.10.10.10/proyect/recursos/upload/1.jpg",
            "pivot": {
              "premio_id": 1,
              "imagen_id": 1
            }
          }
        ],
        "inventario": {
          "premio_id": 1,
          "saldo": "10"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}